# Wpf Close popup when ListboxItem is selected

Tags: wpf, listbox, popup

I have listbox inside popup. How would I close popup right after I select item from list box;
here is code:

```
 <Popup x:Name="ColorPopup" AllowsTransparency="True" 
 IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=ColorToggle, Path=IsChecked}" Placement="Bottom" StaysOpen="False" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ColorToggle}">

  <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" Margin="0, 0,5,5" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" Effect="{DynamicResource WindowShadowEffect}">
      <ListBox Name="ColorList" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1, 3, 1, 3"   IsEnabled="True" Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" SelectedItem="{Binding fColor}" SelectionMode="Single" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalListBoxStyle2}" ItemsSource="{Binding FillColors}">
      </ListBox>

   </Border>

</Popup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx) event.

you can either do it in code-behind:

```cs
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // ColorPopup.IsOpen = false; ?? or ColorToggle.IsChecked = false; 
}
```

```xml
<ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged_1" ... />
```

or maybe if you use MVVM pattern...

It could be something like this for example for MVVM-Light:

```xml
<ListBox ...>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=ClosePopupCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

Or Prism could be almost the same :

```
 <ListBox>
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
           <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=ClosePupupCommand}" />
           </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </ListBox>
```

Or if you have dirty mind you could also close popup in `fColor` property setter. :)

```cs
    public object fColor
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fColorField;
        }

        set
        {
            this.fColorField= value;
            IsColorToggelChecked = false;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.fColor);
        }
    }
```